# Dynamically allocating a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been reading around and I've been applying what I've been reading to my code but I am not sure if I am missing something.. the 2d array is suppose to mirror sudoku.
I know the problem area is in my arrayMake function.
My professor recommended using a cast with the malloc call so:
`sudoku = (int**)malloc(sudokus*sizeof(int*));` but that did not work for me.

```
int main(){
    int sudokus;
    int** sudoku;
    sudokus = getUserInfo();
    sudoku = arrayMake(sudokus);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE*sudokus), i++;){
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE, j++;){
            printf("Numbers[%d][%d]:%d", i, j, sudoku[i][j]);
        }
    }*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int getUserInfo(){
    int sudokus;
    printf("How many Sudokus are you checking today?\n");
    scanf("%d{^\n]\n", &sudokus);

    return sudokus;
}

int** arrayMake(int sudokus){
    int **sudoku;
    int realsize;
    realsize = 9 * sudokus;

    sudoku = malloc(realsize*sizeof(int*));
    if (sudoku == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < realsize, i++;){
        sudoku[i] = malloc(9 * sizeof(int));

        if (sudoku[i] == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocaiton failed");
            return 0;
                            }

    }

    return sudoku;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to allocate an array of _pointers_ or an array of _ints_?

Comment: This is probably where I am a bit confused, as what I was planning on doing was allocating the rows so, 9 rows * the user input because the user can input multiple sudokus. then I wanted just 9 columns. So an so I would assume an array of pointers that point to ints?

Comment: To allocate a 2D array of `int`s, just allocate the number of rows times the number of columns times `sizeof(int)`.  You don't need to make a new allocation for each row or each column.

Comment: what is your `realsize` ? Do you mean it's always as `realsize = 9 * sudokus;` ?

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @artm yea I know i could just put sudokus * 9 instead but I was just trying to find out what the issues could be.

Comment: All your for loops are screwy. `for (int i = 0; i < realsize, i++;)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < realsize; i++)`

Comment: @PaulRooney in the current code above I compile, I enter a number it returns the number of sudokus I want back to main, where I put it into arrayMake, I try to use malloc here but it just returns NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My professor recommended using a cast with the malloc call so: sudoku = (int**)malloc(sudokus * sizeof(int*)); but that did not work for me.

To dynamically allocate for 2D array, you usually need to do two steps. Your code is not clear as you include a `realsize = 9 * sudokus` which doesn't make sense. Anyway, for simplicity, lets assume your sudoku is a 3x3 matrix. You'll need to:

1. Allocate for the pointer to pointer to int:

   ```
   int **sudoku = malloc( 3 * sizeof( int * ) );
   ```
2. Allocate for each of the individual pointer to int:

   ```
   for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
       sudoku[i] = malloc( 3 * sizeof( int ) );
   ```

Comment: Alright so that code made sense, the reason I had realsize is because the user should be able input the number of sudoku grids (so how many 9x9 grids) he is going to input into the program. I was trying to find a way to extend the amount of rows, while keeping 9 columns. I assume you do this by changing the first malloc call?

Comment: You need to change both `malloc` calls to 9 instead of 3.

Comment: Algiht yea Its all working fine now even got it going with calloc, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I see your problem exists in your `for` loops where you have:

`for (i = 0;i < realsize , i++)`

when you really meant:

`for (i = 0;i < realsize ; i++)`
                         ^
Note the change of `,` to `;`

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d{^\n]\n", &sudokus);` is a mistake.

I guess you meant the `{` to actually be a `[` but the format string is still wrong even after that change. I think you intended to consume the rest of the input, up to and including a newline character. However, your format string does not actually do that.

Scanf'ing for `\n` actually means *consume any amount of whitespace*, so in fact this code (with the `[` fix) would continue waiting for input until there was a newline, and also another non-whitespace character typed after the newline.

Better would be:

```
scanf("%d", &sudokus);
int ch;
while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF ) { }
```

There are a few different ways to achieve the same goal.  (Note that scanning for `%d[^\n]%c` is not one of them; that string is also broken).

Also I would suggest a different variable name than `sudokus`. It's confusing having two similarly-named variables `sudoku` and `sudokus`. Name it something that reflects its meaning.

---

For allocating your array, it would be much simpler to take out the `arrayMake` function and write something like:

```
int sudoku[9][9];
```

(I couldn't figure out what `sudokus` was supposed to mean or what `realsize` was going to be, but you could put your intended dimension inside the square brackets there).